# Meaning of 'read the service'

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following is from The African Queen by C. S. Forester

> "I'll bury 'im, Miss," said Allnutt. "Don't you worry yourself, Miss.
>   I'll do it all right. I know some of the **service**. I've 'eard it
>   often enough."
>
> Rose pulled herself together.
>
> "I have my prayer book here. I can **read the service**," she said,
>   keeping her voice from trembling.

I am guessing the 'service' here means a funeral service because they are about to bury someone. Then how can you **read the funeral service**?

Does the second 'service' mean a 'prayer'? Or does 'read the service' mean 'read passages from the prayer book during the service'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Read the service" is an idiomatic way to say "Read the text of the standard service from the prayer book".

You could also say *do* the service (especially if you have memorized it and are not reading from the book), or *perform* the service (if you are acting in a more-or-less *official* capacity).  You can also *give* the service (in the same way as to *give* a performance) or *lead* the service.

Comment: @whitecap "Give the service" is another.

Answer (score 2):

"service" is not only the ceremony but, as you say, the passages from the prayer book.

See under 3a [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/service):

> 3 a : a form followed in worship or in a religious ceremony - the burial service

Even the first "service" might mean all the steps that have to be followed when burying someone, prayers included.